# What is the time taken to process all the requests?

Tags: database

We have a database that allows 2 concurrent writes and 3 concurrent reads. Each read/write operation takes 10ms to complete. What is the time taken to process all the requests (all requests are assumed to be coming in at the same instance and are operating on a single row in a table) - 1. write, write, write, write, read, read, read, read 2. write, write, read, read, read:

```
1. 30 ms 2. 10ms
1. 60 ms 2. 10ms
1. 10 ms 2. 10ms
1. 20 ms 2. 10ms
1. 10ms 2. 20ms
1. 60ms 2. 30ms
```

Comment: What have you attempted at your homework yet? What do you think is the correct answer, and why?

Comment: Sample data as a *table* with desired results would help.  Also, tag with the database you are using.  And, this type of problem does not seem suitable for a database.

Comment: @GMB i think last option is correct

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is a bit tricky. You are allowed two concurrent writes on the database, but it is mentionned that all operations happen on the same row. Two sessions cannot write to the same row concurrently, so all write operations are happening sequentially in this case. While writes are in progress, reads are locked.

Scenario 1 is 4 writes and 4 reads: 4 writes take 40 ms. Then 3 reads can be performed in parallel, in 10 ms. The last read takes 10 ms more. That's a total of 60 ms.

Scenario 2 is 2 writes and 3 reads - with the same logic, you get 30 ms.

=> Out of the given list of options, the last one is the solution.